# Lambda response is not able to "Set-Cookie" in browser

Tags: reactjs, node.js, amazon-web-services, cookies, aws-lambda

I am sending this Object from the lambda response

```
const authCookie = cookie.serialize("authToken", token, {
  httpOnly: true,
  maxAge: 60 * 60 * 60,
  secure: false,
  path: "/",
  sameSite: "none",
});

return {
  statusCode: 200,
  headers: {
    "Set-Cookie": authCookie,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({ data: {}, message: "Successfully logged in!" }),
};
```

and calling the API like this

```
              fetch(
              "https://123.execute-api.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/prod/user/login",
              {
                method: "POST",
                // mode: "no-cors",
                // credentials: "include",
                body: JSON.stringify({
                  phone: "+8420216743",
                  password: "1234",
                }),
              }
            )
              .then((response) => {
                console.log("hello response", response)
                if (!response.ok) {
                  throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
                }
                return response.json();
              })
              .then((data) => {
                console.log("data received: ", data)
              })
              .catch((error) => {
                console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
              });
```

Though I am receiving the "Set-Cookie" in the response headers, but in Application -> Cookies tab there are no cookies set.

can someone please help me to resolve this issue?
Thanks in advance